# Send an image to server through fetch using expo-image-picker React Native

Tags: expo, react-native

I want to upload and image from my gallery using expo-image-picker and send it to the server through fetch.

**expo-image-picker to Upload image Code:**

```
const [photo, setPhoto] =  React.useState(null)
  const chooseImage = async ()=> {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect:[4,3],
      quality:1
    })
    console.log(result)
    if(!result.cancelled){
      setPhoto(result.uri)
    }
  }
```

**Fetch Code:**

```
export const createRestaurantFetch = (endpoint, inputName, inputType, inputDescription, inputAddress, img, touken)=> {    
    
  let bearer = 'Bearer ' + touken;    

  var files = new FormData();
 files.append('name',inputName)
 files.append('type',inputType)
 files.append('description',inputDescription)
 files.append('address',inputAddress)
 files.append('photo',img)

console.log(files)    

    fetch(endpoint, {
      method: "POST", 
      body: files,    
      headers:{              
        'Authorization': bearer
      }
      }).then(res =>{ 
        /* console.log("POST RESPONSE: "+JSON.stringify(res)); */
        /* console.log(res.status); */
        if(res.status==200) {          
          
          res.json().then((data) => {alert(data.message)});     

        }else res.json().then((data) => {alert(data.msg)});
      
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
      /* .then(response => console.log(response)); */
}
```

**console.log(files) shows:**

```
FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "name",
      "Resto",
    ],
    Array [
      "type",
      "Fastfood",
    ],
    Array [
      "description",
      "Atnight",
    ],
    Array [
      "address",
      "Springfield",
    ],
    Array [
      "photo",
      "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540daolavez%252Fubereats/ImagePicker/dfaedaaf-3c1f-49ea-88ce-e62c9e674115.jpg",
    ],
  ],
}
```

**Function that receives body of fetch on server side:**

```
export const createRestaurant = async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  const body=req.body;
  const files = req.files;
  try {
    
    if (!files || Object.keys(files).length === 0 || !files.photo ) {
      res.status(400).json({
          done: false,
          msg: 'There is no photo uploaded, please try again.'
        });
    }          
  
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
};
```

[image]

So first I fill the inputs(that is the data you see in the first line of Fetch Code), then I upload the image as you can see, then I hit "Create" button and it executes the **Fetch Code**, and then you can see in the content of the formData in the **console.log(files)** just so you know it's wrapping the data well to send it, and in the end the response from the server is the msg you see in the code which is `'There is no photo uploaded, please try again.'` meaning that it doesn't recognize the file that I send. I'm not sure how I can achieve this, any suggestions?

By the way, that `img` parameter in the first line of the **Fetch Code** is the image that I'm passing from a function to the Fetch